# Windows 8 xml file writing

Tags: c#, xml, exception, windows-8

I have a problem with writing to xml file, placed in my application folder( windows 8, metro style). I’m getting Unauthorized AccessException when I’m trying to open file in read/write mode. I’ve done a lot of research, but still nothing. I tried this solution:

```
var sf = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"data.xml");
        XmlDocument xmlDoc;
        using (var stream = await sf.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            xmlDoc = await XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(sf);
            XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
            XmlElement xe = xmlDoc.CreateElement("debt");

            XmlElement id = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Id");
            id.InnerText = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            XmlElement name = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Name");
            name.InnerText = d.Name;

            XmlElement surname = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Surname");
            surname.InnerText = d.Surname;

            xe.AppendChild(id);
            xe.AppendChild(name);
            xe.AppendChild(surname);

            root.AppendChild(xe);
        }
        if (xmlDoc != null)
            await xmlDoc.SaveToFileAsync(sf);
```

But again exception occur in line where I'm opening stream.

thx for your help

Comment: What is the value of Package.Current.InstalledLocation.
Have you tried running it (of Visual Studio) as administrator? Even though that may not be a solution it could be an indicator of whats wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync represents where you application is installed which is an area you cannot directly write files to. Use the following

Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation

or

Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path

I am using the former and it works fine, see http://metrorssreader.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/18082#263004